# Using flex order property to re-arrange items for desktop and mobile views

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 3 divs inside a container. There are no nested divs.

I am using flex and `order` property.

On mobile, it is ok with `order` property.

But on larger screens it fails.

I did not use a container div for divs 2 and 3 in order to order them as 2,1,3 on mobile.

[image]

HTML FILE

```
<div class="container">
<div class="orange">1</div>
<div class="blue">2</div>
<div class="green">3</div>
</div>
```

CSS FILE

```
/*************** MOBILE *************/
.container
{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

}
div.blue
{
    order:1;
    width: 100%;
}
div.orange
{
    order:2;
    width: 100%;
}
div.green
{
    order:3;
    width: 100%;

}
/***************************/
@media screen and (min-width:1200px)
{
.container
{
    justify-content: space-between;
}
div.blue
{
    order:2;
    width: 36%;
}
div.orange
{
    order:1;
    width: 60%;
}
div.green
{
    order:3;
    width: 36%;
}
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40098473/3761177

Comment: For people who don't care whether the solution uses grids see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-vlgtnr?file=style.css

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829567/change-div-order-with-css-depending-on-device-width

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your layout, using `row wrap` for the desktop view will be difficult, if not impossible, to implement with CSS. At a minimum, things would get overly complex. Why?

Because flexbox is not a grid system. It's a layout system designed to align content by distribution of space in the container.

In flexbox, items in a `row wrap` container must wrap to *new rows*. This means that div3 cannot wrap beneath div2. It must wrap beneath div1.

*Here's how items wrap in a flex container with `row wrap`:*

[image]

If div3 were to wrap under div2, that wouldn't be a *row*, that would be a *grid*, and flex items are confined to a straight, unbending row.

Put another way, you can't make a flex item wrap under another item in the same row.

As a result, white space created by items that aren't the tallest in the row is preserved in each column, creating unsightly gaps.

[image]

For your desired layout to work in `row wrap`, flex items would have to exit their row in order to close the gap – maybe with absolute positioning – which flexbox cannot do.

One way to align the items would be to wrap div2 and div3 in their own container. This new container would be a sibling to div1. It can then become a nested flex container with `flex-direction: column`. Now the gaps are gone and  layout looks right.

Except, in this particular case, you need the `order` property to work (meaning all items must have the same parent), so a nested flex container is out of the question.

What may work is `column wrap` instead of `row wrap`:

```css
/*************** MOBILE *************/

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px; /* necessary so items know where to wrap */
}
div.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
div.blue {
  order: -1;
  background-color: aqua;
}
div.green {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
.container > div {
  width: 100%;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
/***************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  .container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  div.orange {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    width: 50%;
  }
  div.blue {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    width: 50%;
    order: 0;
  }
  div.green {
    flex-basis: 50%;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="orange">1</div>
  <div class="blue">2</div>
  <div class="green">3</div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtxxxx2h/)

Here are two other options:

- [**Desandro Masonry**](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

  > Masonry is a JavaScript grid layout library. It
  >   works by placing elements in optimal position based on available
  >   vertical space, sort of like a mason fitting stones in a wall.
  >
  > *<sup>source: http://masonry.desandro.com/</sup>*
- [**CSS Grid Layout Module Level 1**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/)

  > This CSS module defines a two-dimensional grid-based layout system, optimized for user interface design. In the grid layout model, the children of a grid container can be positioned into arbitrary slots in a predefined flexible or fixed-size layout grid.
  >
  > *<sup>source: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/</sup>*

Related post: [Is it possible for flex items to align tightly to the items above them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276)

Comment: Is it worth adding that a wrapper of boxes 2 and 3 is a possibility where `display:contents` is available? Just for completeness. This is an excellent canonical answer.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without hard coding the height?  IE Set the height to the taller of 1 or 2+3.

Comment: @WhiteleyJ, consider posting a question with all your details, including the relevant code.