# Flexbox: make arbitrary item a sidebar

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I know there are a lot of questions related to css sidebars and flexbox but my case is a bit different.

I have 4 divs and want to make for example the 3rd div a sidebar in larger screens, so in small screen all 4 items follow their markup order, but in large I want to take that 3rd div and put it on the lefthand side of all the other divs with 25% width.

There is a solution with `position: absolute` but this causes an issue when the sidebar div is larger than all the others together and overlaps other content.

My approach is playing with flexbox but I can't get it to work properly, what I have until now is [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BuschFunker/trbb49oz/1/):

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  .sidebar {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    order: -1;
  }

  .column {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
```

Now there are some issues with this one:

1. If I don't give `.flex` a height, the whole concept doesn't work, but I must not give it a fixed height...
2. The `.columns` will get wrapped individually on very small screens when their content exceeds the height of `.flex`.
3. `.sidebar` will still overlap other content if it's content height is larger than `.flex`'s height.

So as you see my problem technically lies in the required height of `.flex`, do you see a solution there or might the whole approach using flexbox not be very sensible in this case?

Comment: You need nested flexboxes but that would mean you can't change the order....at least until `display:contents`  gets more browser support.

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644585/using-flex-order-property-to-re-arrange-items-for-desktop-and-mobile-views