# How to layout mis-matched stacked content with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Right now we have this layout, and we're using some JS math to make it work - i'm thinking it would be really cool if we could kill the JS and just use flexbox. I've been working through and having some issues figuring out how this would work. Any suggestions?

[image: Landing Page]

Comment: Please consider the guidelines when posting a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: That said, here's a post that may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39645224/3597276

Comment: Flexbox is a great tool for laying out along a single dimension. The layout you defined could be achieved easily with the grid layout, but that's still not finalized, much less implemented in browsers. Possible to use flexbox though... each column would be a flex container with their `flex-direction` set to `column`. You would then need a flex container for those three columns with a `flex-direction` set to `row`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the heights of your elements are mismatched but their widths aren't. You could just put the elements in a flex container and apply the properties:

```
flex-direction: column;
flex-wrap: wrap;
```

You may want to edit your question to address what specifically you're having problems with.