# Push two elements onto the same row if there's enough space with CSS?

Tags: css

In this jsfiddle you'll see that there's enough space for a third block under the second block. Is it possible to push the third block under the second block so that there's only two rows?

https://jsfiddle.net/byokdm8o/

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 20rem;
}

.item {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: .2rem;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: not with flexbox: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39645224/3597276

Comment: and here... http://stackoverflow.com/q/34480760/3597276

Comment: If they don't need to be flex then just old-school left floats work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you float the `.item`s left, they'll stack that way.

```css
.list {
  width: 20rem;
}

.item {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: .2rem;
  float: left;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With such margins between those elements, the solution might be:

```
.list {
  width: 20rem;
}

.item {
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: .2rem;
  float: left;
}

.item:nth-child(1) {
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you need to use flexbox. i am sure there are other ways as well, but here is an amazing tut on flexbox if you are interested:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/