# CSS - How to change divs order

Tags: html, css

I have a div that shows an image and text and i load the content with a `foreach` and i need to invert the order div in second row of foreach.

First div shows:

```
Image - Text
```

Second div shows:

```
Text - Image
```

For example:

```css
.content
{
  width:100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.content .image, .content .text
{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

.content .image img
{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>text1</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: well you can use float: left / right  ???

Comment: but how can i do that in second row the float is right? @fernando

Comment: Do you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32829567/change-div-order-with-css-depending-on-device-width/32829829#32829829

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with at least 2 options

**1. using flexbox see below**

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.content .image,
.content .text {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.content .image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.content:nth-child(even) {
  flex-direction: row-reverse
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>text1</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2. using float:right see below**

```css
.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.content .image,
.content .text {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.content .image img {
  width: 100%;
}

.content:nth-child(even) .image{
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>text1</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <span>text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```