# How do I right-align elements in a flexbox layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a simple section which I want to display clothes data,  here is what I would like to have:

[image: Desired layout example]

**UPDATE Explanation of what I want.**
[image]

I am not able to align elements on the right side as shown in the image above; I tried a few different ways, but nothing worked. What do I need to do to get what I want using flexbox?

```css
.data{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.data-right{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.data-top-right-top_right{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
   <div class="data-left">
      <div clas="data-left-top">
         <p>
            jest tekstem stosowanym 
         </p>
      </div>
      <div clas="data-left-bottom">
         <p>
            jest tekstem stosowanym 
         </p>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="data-right">
      <div class="data-right">
         <div clas="data-right-top">
            <div class="data-right-top_left">
               <a href="https://ibb.co/em6zfK"><img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/em6zfK/piekna_bestia.jpg" alt="piekna_bestia" border="0"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="data-right-top_right">
               <ul>
                  <li>Calvin Clain</li>
                  <li>SM</li>
                  <li>200</li>
               </ul>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div clas="data-right-bottom">
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <span>Total price</span>
                  <span>200</span>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <span>Total price</span>
                  <span>200</span>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <span>Total price</span>
                  <span>200</span>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my demo JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/ypv1cur6/19/

Note: data in shown in the JSFiddle is just for demonstration purposes; it is not real code that would display the same as the image above.

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem with your code.

Comment: @Michael_B what do u mean?

Comment: It's not clear what you want.

Comment: I think you should arrange your HTML in a different way.. insert into the data-right div only 2 divs (one for the image and one for description).
then arrange them with css

Comment: @Michael_B I have updated the image what I would like to have check now

Comment: @SeReGa sorry bro I updated the right image , now check  , I want my data to look like the image showing  in right side div

Comment: @user9964622 Can you be more clear about what your problem is? How exactly does your code output differ from your desired output? E.g. do you want the bullet lists to be on top of each other? Do you want there to be a photo beside each list? Etc.

Comment: hard to follow with these many imbrication , before styling you should build an html structure that is readable on its own (no style) https://jsfiddle.net/ypv1cur6/27/ . can you clarify or check the bits of codeor screenshot  you shared ?

Comment: @TylerH  updated the question with image explanation

Comment: @user9964622 Does the [`order` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32829829/2756409) do what you want? That answer isn't quite directly applicable here because you have more convoluted markup, but it might help you get where you can handle the rest on your own.

Comment: @TylerH U can try urself bro  here is the jsfiddle I tried different ways, the left side is okay only the right side of those two big div  https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/ypv1cur6/19/

Comment: @user9964622 Actually I'd rather help you help yourself than do it all for you :-)

Comment: flex-wrap and width missing ? https://jsfiddle.net/ypv1cur6/38/

Comment: I tried order didnt work , as you can seee here order does not help that is whay I said u can try urself,    the problem is not ordering , problem is bottom elements jump to the top div in right side and those deserved to be in right side of image goes down

Comment: @G-Cyr put that as answer bro , simple as that :(  I will accept your solution quickly as hell , aajajaja thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might be missing some width and flex/wrapping setting:

```css
.data {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
/* added */
.data-right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}

.data-right-top {
  display: flex;
}

.data-right-bottom {
  width: 100%;
}
/* end update */

.data-top-right-top_right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="data">
  <div class="data-left">
    <div clas="data-left-top">
      <p>
        jest tekstem stosowanym
      </p>
    </div>
    <div clas="data-left-bottom">
      <p>
        jest tekstem stosowanym
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="data-right">
    <div class="data-right">
      <div class="data-right-top">
        <div class="data-right-top_left">
          <a href="https://ibb.co/em6zfK"><img src="https://thumb.ibb.co/em6zfK/piekna_bestia.jpg" alt="piekna_bestia" border="0"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="data-right-top_right">
          <ul>
            <li>Calvin Clain</li>
            <li>SM</li>
            <li>200</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="data-right-bottom">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <span>Total price</span>
            <span>200</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Total price</span>
            <span>200</span>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Total price</span>
            <span>200</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ypv1cur6/38/