# Flexbox - first column full height

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I make the first `.item` (green box) 100% height ?

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
border: 1px solid red;
background: #8282e0;
width: 50%;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
background: #a6f7a6;
height: 100%;
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
<h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
<h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
<h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen - https://codepen.io/afelixj/pen/eavVJw

Comment: Do you have to use flexbox or can you use grid?

Comment: Flexbox isn't going to be able to do this without changing your markup. As @JoeB. says, grid can do this.

Comment: you can't do that when a flexbox *wraps*. CSS grids do better.. a similar requirement [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604932/ordering-flex-items) but along with ordering too

Comment: There is no need of all this css to get this result, just change the structure and remove all the CSS, Check my answer bewlow

Answer (score 4):

This is how I would do it (I don't know a way to make it work if you need to put the three headers exactly under each other, like rendering them with a for loop)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
}

.itemCont {
  display: flex;
  background: #8282e0;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #5691f3;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="itemCont">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Item Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="itemCont">
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Item Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <h3>Item Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by changing `flex-direction` to `column` and applying a fixed height to `.wrap`

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 123px;
}
.item {
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #8282e0;
    width: 50%;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
    background: #a6f7a6;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
<h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
<h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
<h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whats the use of `flex` if you are doing it this way. This can be acheived without flex. Try `float:left` to `.item`.

Comment: you have given static height to 1st item you didn't mention that in the description and what is the content in item2 or item 3 is increased.. will it take the height?

Comment: better to use grid.

Comment: I agree it's better to use grid but the question is how to do it in flexbox so that's my answer.

Comment: You didnt use the `flex` . if you are still playing with width.  Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Comment: I have achieved the same result by Flex by just changing some code structure only.
Check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: #8282e0;
  flex:1;
}

.item-inner {
  flex: 1;
  justify-content:center;
  height:100px;
}
.wrap-inner{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
}
.item:nth-child(1) {
  background: #a6f7a6;
  height: 200px;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item item-outer">
    <h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item wrap-inner">
    <div class="item-inner">
      <h3>Item Title</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="item-inner">
      <h3>Item Title</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would be apt use of `flex` property and altering the height.

Comment: You code have extra HTML and CSS, although this result doesn't need so much HTML at least, Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of the extra CSS, just change the structure and Give background colors as per your need.

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.wrap {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
border: 1px solid red;background: #8282e0;
}
.wrap > .item{width: 50%;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h3>Item Title</h3>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```